# How do I programmatically set default role for new users?

Tags: user-roles, users, user-registration

I would like new users of the blog to have custom role, rather then Subscriber. How do I set this programmatically? I know that it can be changed from the backend.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This allows plugins to easily hijack the default role while they're active.

```
// Hijack the option, the role will follow!
add_filter('pre_option_default_role', function($default_role){
    // You can also add conditional tags here and return whatever
    return 'subscriber'; // This is changed
    return $default_role; // This allows default
});
```

I use it to make sure some plugins that need subscriber roles get it regardless of Administrator attempts to change :)

*Regards*.

Answer (score 8):

When a new user is created through the [`wp_insert_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) function, the role is set with the `set_role()` method of the `User` class and is set to the default user role.

The default user role is retrieved from the database `get_option('default_role')` and can be set via the Admin Dashboard by going to Settings > General > New User Default Role.

If you've registered your new role (using [`add_role()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role), it should be available there to choose from.

Alternatively, for more control you can hook into the `user_register` or `profile_update` actions to then `set_role` on them conditionally, or however else you like.

Comment: I will mark your one as correct, although real answer turned out to be as simple as update_option('default_role', 'custom_role_name') upon activation of the plugin.

Comment: Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 6):

After you created the user using

```
$user_id = wp_create_user( $user_login, $pas1, $user_email );
```

Create the user object

```
$user = new WP_User($user_id);
```

Then set the role

```
$user->set_role('editor');
```

You can replace the 'editor' role with any of the following:

- Administrator
- Editor
- Author
- Contributor
- Subscriber

Comment: make sure that the role is lowercased, author, editor, administrator, contributor, subscriber

Answer (score 1):

Put it into the Pluging or functions.php of your theme

```
//Make 'Client' a default role

update_option('default_role','client');
```

Comment: Why?? It serves no purpose to put your code somewhere without knowing what it does or how it works

Comment: That's not good solution. This will run update query if not put in special action on each request.