# How to change user starting role in WordPress MultiSite?

Tags: multisite, users, user-roles, multisite-user-management

I am using WordPress MultiSite. Where can I change user starting role?

It does not show under Settings > General > New User Default Role.

Comment: If you mean changing the default role assigned to users when they register on your site, see Settings → General → ["New User Default Role"](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-allow-user-registration-on-your-wordpress-site/).

Comment: basically, I am using multisite WordPress setting so it does not showing me this option here.

Comment: I can confirm the option linked is not present in multisite in the expected locations, or in the settings screen of the network admin

Comment: I would note that it can be done in code as described here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31791/how-do-i-programmatically-set-default-role-for-new-users

Comment: no it is also not on the network admin side .I remember that I see this option at somewhere but could not find this out now.

Answer (score 1):

I just follow these steps. And its done now.
So if you want to change this, you’ve got a few options open to you:

Go to “My Sites” –> “Network Admin” –> “Sites” –> “All Sites” and select “Edit” on the site that you want to set the default role for, then click “Settings”. Scroll down and you should see “Default Role”. Set the role to ‘subscriber’(whatever you want) and save.